# react-native: axios get 500 internal server error

Tags: javascript, http, react-native, get, expo

The code should return list of album objects in the console, but is not returning it and instead getting a 500 internal server error.

Error : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l29Ho.png)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

class AlbumList extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
      axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
        .then(function(response){
          console.log(response);
        })
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <Text> Albums ! </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default AlbumList;
```

Comment: If it's internal server error you should check what error happen in server.

Comment: The endpoint https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums is working fine, you should write your network calls in componentdidmount.

User response.data to fetch the data from the endpoint once it is received by axios.

Answer (score 1):

can u try this,

```
axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums',
    }).then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);

    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If API return 500 it means **error on server side**. Not on React-native or front-end Side

Comment: so is there nothing I can do?

Comment: No. if  only  API developer can handle this issue. if you are making api than resolve it otherwise ask to API developer

Comment: You can gracefully handle the response by properly parse the response code to avoid the crash.

Answer (score 0):

I was watching the exact same course and had this problem. As you can see if you read through the questions there, it appears that React Native has some compatibility issues with axios.

My problem was fixed by doing this:

```
componentWillMount() {
    fetch("https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));
}
```